# File not found exception using http connection

Tags: android

I have to post xml input http://180.151.60.73/Sales/service.asmx/UpdateOpportunity?xml= it shows exception as,

```
 03-21 09:51:07.483: WARN/System.err(2531): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://180.151.60.73/Sales/service.asmx/UpdateOpportunity?xml=
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at com.jems.common.ParentActivity.getXmlData(ParentActivity.java:218)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at com.jems.salesforce.SalesEditActivity.onClick(SalesEditActivity.java:2989)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-21 09:51:07.493: WARN/System.err(2531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-21 09:51:07.503: WARN/System.err(2531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-21 09:51:07.503: WARN/System.err(2531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-21 09:51:07.503: WARN/System.err(2531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    03-21 09:51:07.503: WARN/System.err(2531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    03-21 09:51:07.503: WARN/System.err(2531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have used this code for http connection

```
byte[] xm=(xmlUrl).getBytes();
                    StringBuffer b1=new StringBuffer();
                    b1.append(xmlUrl);
                       Log.i("xmlurl",""+ xm);
                       SalesActivity sa =new SalesActivity();
                URL url = new URL("http://180.151.60.73/Sales/service.asmx/UpdateOpportunity?xml=");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SendChunked", "True");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.connect();

                OutputStream out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                out.write(xm);    // send request
                InputStream response = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                doc = db.parse(response);
                //receive response
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
```

xmlurl as input also this length is too long...

Comment: the error is obvious >_> *cough* file not found *cough*

Comment: ya its shows 404 file not found exception..how to resolve this?

Comment: value pass in parameter not contain any space or encode with http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html
i had also face same problem and i got solution with encode value and then pass to query

Comment: i have used URLEncoder.encode(xmlurl) for input...the input is too long...

Comment: @user1235251 so have you tried it??

Comment: ya..i already tried that...i guess the problem as the length of url...it exceeds more than 3000 charecters..

Comment: @user1235251 i dont think so that length is responsible...

Comment: @user1235251 xml parameter also missing in url

Answer (score 1):

Use

connection.getErrorStream();

Instead of

connection.getInputStream();